# App crashes when I attempt to run it with an iOS xcframework that relies on the LibTorch-Lite CocoaPod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcframework

1. MyLibrary: CocoaPod that I am trying to install and run but failing. (https://github.com/steve-ham/MyLibrary) (Includes below 'MyFramework')
2. MyFramework: iOS framework with 'LibTorch-Lite' CocoaPod dependency. (https://github.com/steve-ham/MyFramework)

When I run 'MyLibrary App' (https://github.com/steve-ham/MyLibrary) I get below error:

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type torch::jit::ErrorReport: 
Unknown custom class type quantized.Conv2dPackedParamsBase. Please ensure it is registered.:
quantized::conv1d(Tensor qx, __torch__.torch.classes.quantized.Conv2dPackedParamsBase packed_weight, float output_scale, int output_zero_point) -> Tensor
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE

terminating with uncaught exception of type torch::jit::ErrorReport: 
Unknown custom class type quantized.Conv2dPackedParamsBase. Please ensure it is registered.:
quantized::conv1d(Tensor qx, __torch__.torch.classes.quantized.Conv2dPackedParamsBase packed_weight, float output_scale, int output_zero_point) -> Tensor
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
```

I used below code to create MyFramework.xcframework from MyFramework project (https://github.com/steve-ham/MyFramework)

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace \
  -scheme MyFramework \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -archivePath "./MyFramework.xcarchive" \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive -workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace \
  -scheme MyFramework \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -archivePath "./MyFramework_sim.xcarchive" \
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
  EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "MyFramework.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework" \
    -framework "MyFramework_sim.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework" \
    -output MyFramework.xcframework
```

I don't encounter this issue with other CocoaPods projects, this happens only with 'LibTorch-Lite'. Is there a fundamental limitation that prevents wrapping 'LibTorch-Lite' into an .xcframework for successful installation and execution in my 'MyLibrary' project? Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I’m not actively looking for the answer, will be focusing on other things for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I found a semi working solution and included it below in case it is still useful for you/ anyone else who stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

After doing the following method and importing the framework into another project, I was not able to release the project(app) to testflight. I'm leaving this answer here in case someone can use it as a stepping stone to find a correct solution.

### Original Answer

I was able to get a working solution for this that has some limitations:

Instead of adding the dependency on libTorch-Lite to my podspec file, I removed the dependency on it and instead embedded the pods framework into my framework like so:

[image: Clicking "Embed & Sign" for the framework target in the General tab of the project settings]

When I built the framework and imported it into another project as a cocoapod, everything worked flawlessly.

### Limitations of this method:

Generally the recommended way to include cocoapods in an xcframework is to run `pod init`, add the pods to the podfile, run `pod install`, and then when building the framework, you run something similar to the following and add all the dependent pods to your podspec file as dependencies.

```
xcodebuild archive \
-workspace MyPackage.xcworkspace \
-scheme MyPackage \
-configuration Release \
-sdk iphoneos \
-archivePath archives/ios_devices.xcarchive \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive \
-workspace MyPackage.xcworkspace \
-scheme MyPackage \
-configuration Release \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-archivePath archives/ios_simulator.xcarchive \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO

rm -rf ./MyPackage.xcframework

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework ./archives/ios_devices.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyPackage.framework \
-framework ./archives/ios_simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyPackage.framework \
-output ./MyPackage.xcframework
```

Doing it like this (not embedding the pods framework and adding the dependencies to the podspec) allows cocopods to handle versions correctly and reduces the chance of having conflicts. When embedding the pod framework, you run the risk that apps/packages that import your package will have the same pod dependency and that will cause errors in the host project.

So, if you are also depending on a commonly used pod, like alamofire, in your framework, there's a good chance it will break whatever app imports it, assuming they also have a dependency on alamofire.

Comment: How could you not include LibTorch-Lite in podspec file and just (embed the LibTorch-Lite pods framework) into your framework? You wouldn’t have LibTorch-Lite pods framework in the first place because it was not included on podspec file.

Comment: LibTorch-Lite was included in my podfile, not my podspec file. That way when I embedded the pods framework into my framework, it was embedding LibTorch-Lite along with it.

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that works.